# Is it safe to pass the event from the main thread to the worker thread and wait for it?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, thread-safety, delphi-xe2

I'm working on such kind of an action queue thread and I would like to wait for a certain action to be performed. I'd like to create the action in main thread, then pass it to the queue thread function (to the end of the queue) and wait for this action to be performed. So I need to distinguish the action I have just queried has been performed and wait for it.

I have a following (pseudo) code and I would like to know

- is it working with Windows event object thread safe ?
- if yes, would this concept be efficient ?

---

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread);
  private
    FEvent: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    procedure DoSomething(const AEvent: THandle);
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  //  is it working with events thread safe ?
  SetEvent(FEvent);
  //  the thread will continue, so I can't use WaitFor
  //  but it won't set this specific FEvent handle again
  //  I'm working on such kind of an action queue, so once the action with ID,
  //  here represented by the FEvent will be processed, it's removed from 
  //  the action queue
end;

procedure TMyThread.DoSomething(const AEvent: THandle);
begin
  FEvent := AEvent;
end;

//  here's roughly what I want to do

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OnceUsedEvent: THandle;
begin
  //  the thread is already running and it's instantiated in MyThread
  //  here I'm creating the event for the single request I need to be performed
  //  by the worker thread
  OnceUsedEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  try 
  //  here I'm passing the event handle to the worker thread (like a kind of
  //  a request ID)
    MyThread.DoSomething(OnceUsedEvent);
  //  and here I want to wait for 10 seconds (and also interrupt this waiting 
  //  when the user closes the application if possible ?) for the thread if
  //  performs my request
    WaitForSingleObject(OnceUsedEvent, 10000);
  finally
  //  close the event handle
    CloseHandle(OnceUsedEvent);
  end;
  //  and continue with something else
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Waiting on the event in the button event handler will block the main thread, so that's not what you want! Maybe you can use an event instead (that is called whenever the thread finished)

Comment: That wait is not going to do what you want. It cannot be interrupted. And why would you want to block for 10s? That's just odd.

Comment: Ideally INFINITE; And it's for renaming action. I need to enter the edit mode of the VirtualTreeView node and keep the editor alive until I get the result of the renaming action from the thread (I have an extra event handler where I need to pass the result if the renaming succeeded and when I exit this event handler the editor is hidden).

Comment: Thanks @David to your point. Now I see it block all message processing thus the whole main thread (form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine. The handle returned from CreateEvent can be freely used by all threads. Anything else would render it pretty useless since this is its primary use :)

Comment: Not necessarily. It seems plausible to me that a handle could be thread-specific, or at least not inherently thread-safe. If another thread wanted access to the same event, it could be that it needs to call DuplicateHandle, or it needs to call CreateEvent itself with the same event name.

Comment: Empirically, the handle can be used from other threads - I have used events in such a way often.

Comment: @RobKennedy that's exactly what I've always done until today when I saw an example that someone just had both threads use the same handle variable...

Answer (score 3):

Do not wait for threads in GUI event handlers.  Don't do it by waiting on events, semaphores or mutexes, sleep() loops, DoEvents loops or any combination thereof.

If you want to communicate with the main thread to signal that something has been processed in a threadpool, look at the PostMessage() API.

Comment: Alternatives to using `PostMessage` when communicating with the main tread are 1) `Thread.Queue` as described here [synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2011/01/30/synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters/#more-135) (this is useful for FireMonkey applications) or 2) using a `thread safe queue` and polling the queue from the main thread with a timer loop.

Comment: 'synchronize-and-queue-with-parameters' is OK-ish, but it makes two system calls just to find out which thread it's running on :(  Using a timer to poll is fine for periodically displaying the most up-to-date value of many variables, but just introduces latency if used to poll a queue.